# django rest framework get data from foreign key relation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I created a user profile using Django auth user so I want to get username, email and phone using UserProfile model serializer, so it is possible to get data from from a foreign-key relation using ModelSerializer in Django rest framework. I am not getting any useful solution from documentation and Google, please help.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=UserProfile
        fields = (phone,'user__username','user__email')
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to define the `username` and `email` fields in your serializer and pass the `source` argument with dotted notation to traverse attributes in the `User` model.

You need to do something like:

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username', read_only=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField(source='user.email', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model=UserProfile
        fields = (phone, username, email)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using rest - i would suggest suggest serializing the user model
something like this

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    phone = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'phone')
```

If you want to achieve the reverse as well:

```
class UserProfileserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.RelatedField(source='user', read_only=True)
    email = serializers.RelatedField(source='user', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
       model = UserProfile
       fields = ('username','email','phone')
```

Comment: thanks for replay but i want to get username ,email and phone using UserProfile serializer not from user user serializer so it is possible or not .

Comment: it throw error :RelatedField.to_representation() must be implemented for field email

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
# import your serializer class
from myapp.serializers import UserProfileSerializer

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    phone = UserProfileSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'phone')
```